# Capturing words and number in parenthesis after a specific word

Tags: python, regex, keyword, matching

I am using regex to find the value using the keyword '`interest at the rate`' from this `interest at the rate of ten percent (10%)`

I tried this

```
re.compile(r'interest at the rate\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){3})').findall(r.decode('utf-8'))
```

and obtained `['of ten percent ']`.

Now, I tried

```
re.compile(r'interest at the rate of\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){3})').findall(r.decode('utf-8'))
```

However, all I get is an empty value, `[]`.

How to get the number 10 from the above line? I want to capture three to four words after the keyword and get the integer value.

Comment: Do you mean you need to get the numeric value inside parentheses after the search string? Try [`r'interest at the rate [^(]*\((\d[\d.]*)'`](http://rextester.com/SLXQ47346)

Comment: Or, if you need the whole string like that, [`r'interest at the rate\s+[^(]*\(\d[\d.]*%\)'`](http://rextester.com/YPPG9652)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why don't you add as an answer instead of commenting while its working ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar In this case, I am not sure what OP wants. `.+`  also works, but might not be what OP needs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew he exactly told he want the number and your first solution gives it.

Comment: @VikasDamodar That is not clear, see *I want to capture three to four words after the keyword and get the integer value*. I think [`r'interest at the rate ([^(]*\((\d[\d.]*)[^)]*\))'`](http://rextester.com/KRJO25480) is what OP might use...

Comment: @dhinar, see [`r'interest at the rate (\w+(?:\s+\w+){2,3})\s*\((\d[\d.]*)[^)]*\)'`](http://rextester.com/JBNOY9657), is it what you want?

Comment: I wanted to get only the number from that line ('10') Wiktor answer is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the number 10 from the above line? I want to capture three to four words after the keyword and get the integer value

So, I understand that you expect to get *three to four words after the keyword* (=`of ten percent`) and the *integer* value (=`10`). I assume the "keyword" is `interest at the rate`, just what you used in the pattern.

Then, you may use

```
import re
s = "interest at the rate of ten percent (10%)"
r = re.compile(r'interest at the rate (\w+(?:\s+\w+){2,3})\s*\((\d+)')
print(r.findall(s))
# => [('of ten percent', '10')]
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/NIV13732).

**Details**

- `interest at the rate` - the keyword
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+){2,3})` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then 2 or 3 sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(`
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

If the number of words can be more than 2 or 3 or can be 1 or 0, replace `{2,3}` with `*`.

If the number can be a float, too, replace `\d+` with `\d[\d.]*`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score -1):

Okay, if I understand the question you can use the following

```
import re

value = "interest at the rate of ten percent (10%)"
regexString = r"^interest at the rate of ten percent \(([0-9]{2})%\)$"

result = re.findall(regexString, value, 0) # Zero is the flag for match all, you can omit this. 

print(result)
```

This will return `['10']`.

Comment: sadly, the above code only works for 2 digit numbers . I want to work for all number like  7%..

Comment: In that case, just remove the restriction, i.e. use ``^interest at the rate of ten percent \(([0-9]+)%\)``